# Javascript switch on undefined property

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to have a switch statement like the following?

```
switch(this.myObject && this.myObject.myProperty){ //... }
```

With the purpose of testing if myObject is defined or not?

Comment: it works with `case undefined:`, but remember switch is strict.

Comment: Why not just an `if`?

Comment: In this case, you will simply have 2 cases - case 'true', case 'false'?

Comment: if you use an if statement you can do `if(typeof myObject.property === "undefined")` to check if it is undefined

Answer (score 0):

```
if (typeof this.myObject !== 'undefined' && typeof this.myObject.myProperty !== 'undefined') {
    switch(this.myObject.myProperty) {
        //...
    }
} else {
    //don't exist
}
```

or:

```
var objectAndPropertyExists = typeof this.myObject !== 'undefined' && typeof this.myObject.myProperty !== 'undefined';
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. Just be aware that in falsy cases, the value could come either from `this.myObject` or `this.myObject.myProperty`.

```js
function f() {
  switch(this.myObject && this.myObject.myProperty){
    case undefined: return 'myObject or myProperty are undefined';
    case 123: return 'myProperty is 123';
    default: return 'something else';
  }
}
console.log(f.call({}));
console.log(f.call({myObject: true }));
console.log(f.call({myObject: false }));
console.log(f.call({myObject: {myProperty:123} }));
console.log(f.call({myObject: {myProperty:456} }));
console.log(f.call({myObject: {myProperty:undefined} }));
```